# Cannot create bucket even if another user no longer own the bucket name

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We are transferring Google cloud storage bucket name (naked domain name) from one user to another. Since we no longer have active account, who own the bucket name, the bucket was deleted from Google cloud storage. And then recreate the same bucket name, but the console panel continue deny to create the bucket with the following error.

```
The bucket you tried to create is a domain name owned by another user.
```

It has been several days, the bucket was deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a bucket that maps to a domain name, the account creating the bucket must be the registered owner of the domain name. Presumably the old account is registered as the owner of the domain. You're going to want to have the new account go through the domain verification process at Google Webmaster Tools: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Here's some more documentation about how to claim ownership of the domain name: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179

Comment: Thanks. It works, but require DNS base verification on webmaster tool. Previously the new account is verify owner of the domain using meta tag, it does not work for Google cloud storage.